# What is maximum length for Zend Cache File backend identifier?

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching

I would like to know what is max length for cache id (backend File or TwoLevels) , can't find this anywhere in docs or source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason for the API to force a limit. It's as big as a PHP string can be, and the length of PHP strings are only limited by the memory of the server.